# When I use Jrebel Debug to run the SpringBoot project, Jrebel is stuck in an infinite loop of class reloading

Tags: jrebel

2023-06-15 17:52:18.468 INFO  [0] [Core] java.net.URLClassLoader@245b4bdc found resource: 'imp-onetimepwd.properties' from 'jar:file:/E:/Maven/repository/com/thunisoft/jy/imp-security-common/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/imp-security-common-1.0.1-20200102.070510-13.jar!/imp-onetimepwd.properties'.
2023-06-15 17:52:18.468 TRACE [0] [Core] java.net.URLClassLoader@245b4bdc searching for resource 'imp-onetimepwd.properties'.
2023-06-15 17:52:18.468 INFO  [0] [Core] java.net.URLClassLoader@245b4bdc found resource: 'imp-onetimepwd.properties' from 'jar:file:/E:/Maven/repository/com/thunisoft/jy/imp-security-common/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/imp-security-common-1.0.1-20200102.070510-13.jar!/imp-onetimepwd.properties'.
2023-06-15 17:52:18.745 TRACE [27] [Modules] ReloadModuleGroup created for com.sun.jmx.remote.util.ClassLoaderWithRepository@2a80b4d6: ac($$M$*jr_69D3D00E624D1BE0*)
2023-06-15 17:52:18.745 TRACE [27] [Modules] Finalizing ab($$M$_jr_69D3D00E624D1BE0_0)
2023-06-15 17:52:18.745 TRACE [27] [Modules] ReloadModuleGroup created for javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$CombinedClassLoader@160d579c: ac($$M$*jr_6D6E1414624E6914*)
2023-06-15 17:52:18.745 TRACE [27] [Modules] Finalizing ab($$M$_jr_6D6E1414624E6914_0)
2023-06-15 17:52:18.745 TRACE [27] [Modules] ReloadModuleGroup created for javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$CombinedClassLoader$ClassLoaderWrapper@42672b6b: ac($$M$*jr_3543C089624F449C*)
2023-06-15 17:52:18.745 TRACE [27] [Modules] Finalizing ab($$M$_jr_3543C089624F449C_0)
2023-06-15 17:52:19.027 TRACE [0] [Core] java.net.URLClassLoader@245b4bdc searching for resource 'imp-detector.properties'.
2023-06-15 17:52:19.027 INFO  [0] [Core] java.net.URLClassLoader@245b4bdc found resource: 'imp-detector.properties' from 'jar:file:/E:/Maven/repository/com/thunisoft/jy/imp-spring-cloud/1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/imp-spring-cloud-1.0.1-20191126.021808-6.jar!/imp-detector.properties'.
2023-06-15 17:52:19.027 TRACE [0] [Core] java.net.URLClassLoader@245b4bdc searching for resource 'imp-detector.properties'.

Keep cycling between imp-security-common-1.0.1-20200102.070510-13.jar and imp-spring-cloud-1.0.1-20191126.021808-6.jar,Please take a look, thanks

change rebel.xml,bug no useful